# google maps api v3: infowindows distorted

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

When I plug in values for x instead of using a for loop, this code works.  But when I use the for loop, the infowindow shows up distorted on the left side of the screen.

What the heel!

> for (var x = 0; x < data.page_size; x++) {
>
> ```
> var position = new google.maps.LatLng(
>   data.events.event[x]['latitude'],
>   data.events.event[x]['longitude']);
>
> marker.push(
>   new google.maps.Marker({
>     position: position, 
>     map: map, 
>     icon: image}
> ));
>
>  google.maps.event.addListener(marker[x], 'click', function() {
>   infowindow.setContent(content[x]);
>   infowindow.open(map, marker[x]);
> });
> ```
>
> }

Comment: use `this` instead of `marker[x]` inside the `click`-callback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An economical way to approach this is to make the marker aware of its own index at the cost of just one Number property per marker, and avoiding the need to form a set of closures containing copies of `content[x]`.

```
for (var x = 0; x < data.page_size; x++) {
    ...
    marker[x].x = x;//make the marker aware of its own index
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker[x], 'click', function() {
        infowindow.setContent(content[this.x]);
        infowindow.open(map, this);
    });
}
```

Providing the `marker` array and the `content` array remain static, or are compatibly managed, then `this.x` will reliably pull out the correct content for each marker.

Answer (score 1):

You must use the closure in this case. Like this:

```
(function(m,c){
    google.maps.event.addListener(m, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.setContent(c);
        infowindow.open(map, m);
    });
})(marker[x],content[x])
```

Comment: Forming a deliberate closure can be a good thing but not in this case for two reasons. (a) `marker[x]` is `this` inside the listener, as Dr.Molle points out above, (b) `content[x]` is possibly a string (it could be a node but we don't know). If it is a string then it will be assigned by value on forming the closure; in other words there will be two copies of all the content strings, one in the original array and one in a set of closures - not good for economy of RAM.

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot: Since strings are immutable in JS, we can assume that JS engines optimize this and share them on assign-by-value. Still, introducing a closure (for `x`) would be better than assigning to custom `x` properties on (foreign) `Marker` instances.

Comment: Thanks for that @Bergi. I'm probably behind the times here. Thinking back (nearly two decades now), it was said (please don't ask me where) that the safe assumption was that strings were passed by value (despite being immutable). I expect that early ECMAScript implementations interpreted the Language Specification differently from each other. Surfing around, I note that today's commentators generally assert that strings are passed by reference, though the Language Specification appears to be unedifying on this point.